# how to convert downloaded video file to text file

Tags: audio, video, text

I have downloaded many video files and it should be converted to text files. Can anybody please help me out to convert a video file into a text? This is very important for my project.. Please suggest the answers soon as possible..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Generally i recommend convert file to `Base64`. On linux You can use `base64` command line tool to convert binary file to text representation.

```
base64 file.avi > file.txt
```

To decode from text file:

```
base64 -d file.txt > file.avi
```

Comment: Is ok for You to convert files to Base64 ?

Comment: yeah.. but how can i convert that to actual words again??

Answer (score 0):

If it's a youtube video then you can just go to more next to save and click open transcript. I found it pretty easy. Then you can copy and paste it into a text file.